# Single-column multipart figure in IEEE Access

Tags: ieeeaccess

I want to have a single-column multipart figure in IEEE Access article.

My current code is like

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Cap}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{A.png}
        \caption{A}
        \label{fig:A}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{B.png}
        \caption{B}
        \label{fig:B}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C.png}
        \caption{C}
        \label{fig:C}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace*{-10pt}
\end{figure}
```

How to re-format this to `\Figure` tag in IEEE Access, for it to become single-column?

---

Working example:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{FooFooFoo}


\author{\uppercase{First A. Author}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Fellow, IEEE},
\uppercase{Second B. Author\authorrefmark{2}, and Third C. Author,
Jr}.\authorrefmark{3},
\IEEEmembership{Member, IEEE}}
\address[1]{National Institute of Standards and 
Technology, Boulder, CO 80305 USA (e-mail: author@boulder.nist.gov)}
\address[2]{Department of Physics, Colorado State University, Fort Collins, 
CO 80523 USA (e-mail: author@lamar.colostate.edu)}
\address[3]{Electrical Engineering Department, University of Colorado, Boulder, CO 
80309 USA}
\tfootnote{This paragraph of the first footnote will contain support 
information, including sponsor and financial support acknowledgment. For 
example, ``This work was supported in part by the U.S. Department of 
Commerce under Grant BS123456.''}

\markboth
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}

\corresp{Corresponding author: First A. Author (e-mail: author@ boulder.nist.gov).}



\begin{abstract}
foo
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
foo
\end{keywords}



\titlepgskip=-15pt
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Cap}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{A.png}
        \caption{A}
        \label{fig:A}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{B.png}
        \caption{B}
        \label{fig:B}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C.png}
        \caption{C}
        \label{fig:C}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace*{-10pt}
\end{figure}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @Imran MWE added.

Comment: If you want the subfigures in one column, replace the `\hfill`s with blank lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear, what you mean with "single column". Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Cap}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{A.png}
        \caption{A}
        \label{fig:A}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{B.png}
        \caption{B}
        \label{fig:B}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{C.png}
        \caption{C}
        \label{fig:C}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\EOD
\end{document}
```

or like this

[image]

where is considered @Imran comment:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Cap}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{A.png}
        \caption{A}
        \label{fig:A}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{B.png}
        \caption{B}
        \label{fig:B}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{C.png}
        \caption{C}
        \label{fig:C}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\EOD
\end{document}
```